# adding one value on table result of case statue

Tags: sql

I want to add one more case on my query. if phone number have product which have FACE, FAST and MOBIL, add 10 point on answer1 alias column.

How can I do that I think I should use union but I can't do algorith

I explain other case

if product is equal FAST and tree_level is equal 0,1,2,3,4,5 and tree_level equal -1 point is 2

and if product is equal MOBIL and tree_level is equal 0,1,2,3,4,5 point is 3

if product is equal FACE and tree_level is equal 0,1,2,3,4,5 point is 3 and tree_level equal -1 point is 2

**ı want to add if number's product have face,mobil,fast product give 10 point**

**produc.DIG_SEF table**

```
product|phone|tree_lev  | start_date              | end_date
___________________________________________________________________________
fast   |98998|0         |2013-06-15 00.00.00.0000 |2013-09-15 00.00.00.0000 
mobil  |98998|0         |2013-06-15 00.00.00.0000 |2013-09-15 00.00.00.0000 
face   |98998|0         |2013-06-15 00.00.00.0000 |2013-09-15 00.00.00.0000 
face   |54545|1         |2013-09-15 00.00.00.0000 |2013-12-15 00.00.00.0000 
mobil  |66545|2         |2013-12-15 00.00.00.0000 |2014-03-15 00.00.00.0000 
mobil  |26545|2         |2013-12-15 00.00.00.0000 |2014-03-15 00.00.00.0000 
face   |43645|1         |2013-09-15 00.00.00.0000 |2013-12-15 00.00.00.0000 
face   |34545|1         |2013-09-15 00.00.00.0000 |2013-12-15 00.00.00.0000 
mobil  |26545|2         |2013-12-15 00.00.00.0000 |2014-03-15 00.00.00.0000
face   |56898|-1        |2014-03-15 00.00.00.0000 |2014-06-15 00.00.00.0000
```

**For Example, phone 98998 have FACE, MOBIL and FAST. I want to give 10 point on answer1**

```
 select
    DS.phone,
    DS.Product,
    DS.Tree_lev,
CASE  
    WHEN DS.Tree_lev IN (-1) And DS.Product LIKE '%FACE%' THEN  2
    WHEN DS.Tree_lev IN (-1) And DS.Product LIKE '%FAST%' THEN c 2
    WHEN DS.Tree_lev >=0 AND DS.Product LIKE '%FACE%' THEN 3 
    WHEN DS.Tree_lev >=0 AND DS.Product LIKE '%MOBIL%' THEN 3 
    WHEN DS.Tree_lev  AND DS.Product LIKE '%FAST%' THEN  2 
    Else DS.Tree_lev 
    END AS Answer1 
    from produc.DIG_SEF AS DS
```

**my query give this output**

```
product|phone|tree_lev  | answer1
___________________________________________________________________________
fast   |98998|0         |2
mobil  |98998|0         |3
face   |98998|0         |3
face   |54545|-1        |2
mobil  |66545|2         |3
mobil  |26545|3         |3
```

**ı want this output**

```
product     |phone| answer1
___________________________________________________________________________
fast        |98998|2
mobil       |98998|3
face        |98998|3
threproduct |98998|10 // **ı want to add this** 
face        |54545|2
mobil       |66545|3
mobil       |26545|3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then the additional rows are found by this query:

```
select 'theproduct', DS.phone, 10
from produc.DIG_SEf
group by DS.phone
having sum(case when product = 'FAST' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when product = 'MOBIL' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when product = 'FACE' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

This returns all `phone` that have all three products.

You can combine this with your query using `union all`:

```
select DS.phone, DS.Product, DS.Tree_lev,
       (CASE WHEN DS.Tree_lev IN (-1) And DS.Product LIKE '%FACE%' THEN  2
             WHEN DS.Tree_lev IN (-1) And DS.Product LIKE '%FAST%' THEN c 2
             WHEN DS.Tree_lev >=0 AND DS.Product LIKE '%FACE%' THEN 3 
             WHEN DS.Tree_lev >=0 AND DS.Product LIKE '%MOBIL%' THEN 3 
             WHEN DS.Tree_lev  AND DS.Product LIKE '%FAST%' THEN  2 
             Else DS.Tree_lev 
        END
       ) AS Answer1 
from produc.DIG_SEf DS
union all
select 'theproduct', DS.phone, 10
from produc.DIG_SEf
group by DS.phone
having sum(case when product = 'FAST' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when product = 'MOBIL' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when product = 'FACE' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
order by phone;
```

Comment: ı do not understand why you give onether table name from produc.DIG_SET ? ı useproduc.DIG_SEf

Comment: AND said mutli-part identifier  on select 'theproduct', DS.phone, 10

Comment: yes it is work thanks dude.. can ı asking question if ı want to add one of start date from product's have can ı do that

Comment: @AdKu . . . you would use an expression like `max(case when product = 'FAST' then startdate end) as FASTStart`.

Comment: hımm but I want to add which number's equal and it have fast,mobil ,fast product's biggest start.date.. :( sory.. this is another question but ı want to develop my algorithm. if you angry this question ı will ask another question. sorry dude if you angry to me

Answer (score 0):

You are right. For additional result records you need a union clause. Assuming there are 1 to 3 records in DIG_SEF for each number, you would want the additional line in case there exist three entries, i.e. all products, for a number.

```
select ...
UNION ALL
select 
    phone,
    'threproduct' as product,
    null as Tree_lev,
    10 AS Answer1 
from produc.DIG_SEF
group by phone
having count(*) = 3
order by 1,4
```

Comment: hım but if there is three mobile it is count ı want to add point for different product. it have to different product face,mobil,fast for adding point not for three produc